# Laravel Eloquent using paginate with whereIn

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi I have a query that looks roughly like this

```
Comment::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.user_id')
    ->whereIn('comments.id', $ids)
    ->paginate(5);
```

where $ids is an array of comment ids. Changing the paginate to get() works but I want to use paginate as it returns many built-in useful results such as next_page_url etc. So how do I modify the query to utilize both whereIn and paginate together?

Comment: there is no issue with the code that you posted, what is the error that you get?

Comment: @Lee What error that you faced ?

Comment: Using paginate I get empty result but using get() I got the intended results. I'll admit this issue is damn weird.

Comment: How do you check the result ?  like : dd(comments) ?

Comment: @Chung Yes I did use dd.

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue later on, I forgot to serialize the object before I return the result. A simple `toArray()` has done the trick.